# Why is my ram usage so high with nothing running? (30% used from 16Gb ram)

Tags: windows, memory, anti-virus, desktop-computer, task-manager

[Task Manager Performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tE4Z.png)
[Task Manager Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9nv3.png)

I used Avast antivirus for some time and the ram used was like this, but a week ago I uninstalled it and it is still 30% usage (4.8Gb from 16Gb 3200mHz ram used). I don t know what to close in order to fall back at 20%.
I think it's an issue because it wasn't like that one month ago and those 5.9 Gb are at a fresh startup (also, it's 20% for like 2 minutes, then it goes up at 30% at startup).

Comment: It would help if you would say which OS you are using. Please clarify whether task manager indicates that Avast is using the 5.9 Gb or whether that is the amount in use upon a fresh startup. You should edit your question to add this information.

Comment: You also need to tell us why you think this is an issue. Empty RAM is wasted RAM

Comment: The relevant information is only visible in the "Memory" view on the "Performance" tab. Please provide a screenshot of that.

Comment: Looks like you may have a non-paged pool leak. You can try following [this guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-poolmon-to-find-a-kernel-mode-memory-leak) to maybe find out which driver is responsible. // [This article](https://medium.com/@clintcolding/finding-memory-leaks-with-poolmon-3da80e479040) may offer a more beginner-friendly description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have lots of odd little services running that are wasting memory.

- MSI Afterburner (and at least two other services that I can see)

  - MSI True Color
  - MSI Central server
- Nvidia (several services)
- LEDKeeper - appears to be something to do with "[Mystic Light](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10TechSupport/comments/hkdnpa/ledkeeper2_in_volume_mixer/)"
- LG Hub - mouse software

Whether or not you consider any of those "expendable" is up to you. The Nvidia stuff might be worth keeping, but I'd consider MSI software somewhat superfluous bloatware depending on the situation.

LG software might be necessary to keep if you want to use mouse profiles but you might live without it. Same goes for whatever Mystic Light is doing, I'd consider anything playing with LEDs in my case to be a complete waste of resources, other people like blinkenlights flashing away distractingly in the corner of their field of view.

At a minimum though, Windows is *hungry* these days. The more memory you have the more it "relaxes" into it. I have 16GB and my machine comes up from a reboot with about 4.5GB in use. A 4GB machine I had came up with 3.5GB in use and fell back to around 2.5GB after a while.

The real question is, does it really matter?

If it wasn't being used, what else would you use it for? If the answer is "not much, if anything" then there's no harm in it being used for *something.*

Comment: That MSI I usually keep closed, I forgot when I took the picture. The LG Hub is for my keyboard RGB, but I didn't knew about the LEDKeeper, so thanks for informing me about that!

Comment: Yep. Memory is a "use it or lose it" resource. You can't save it for later. Any memory not used right now is potential performance (due to reduced I/O) that is forever lost. Windows (like most modern operating systems) goes out of its way to use as much memory as it possibly can.

Answer (score 0):

I found that a recent update from Windows did that, by using some new programs, so I think the problem is solved. Thanks to everyone who helped me!:)))

Comment: If anyone wants to put a new answer feel free to post. Maybe you found something else.